# My predicate to calculate the depth of a binary tree branch isn't working

Tags: prolog, depth

I'm trying to calculate the depth of the left branch in binary trees but the predicate keeps failing!

I've tried `trace.` and I've arrived to the conclusion that the fail status must come from the `is\2` functor, but I still can't figure out what the problem is...

```
leftdepth(void,0).
leftdepth(tree(_,Left,_),N):-leftdepth(Left,N),N is N+1.
```

I expect the output of the query `leftdepth(tree(3,tree(2,tree(5,void,void),tree(7,void,void)),void),3).` to be true, but it outputs false.

Comment: `N is N+1` can never succeed in Prolog because you cannot modify variables.

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me solve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call:

```
N is N + 1.
```

does not make much sense. In Prolog a variable can be unified with a value, but you then can no longer "re-unify" it with a *different* value. One of the concepts of *declarative programming* is that variables can not change value.

What you can do is create an extra variable, one thus for the level of the "*child*", and one for the level of the "*parent*":

```
leftdepth(void, 0).
leftdepth(tree(_,Left,_), N1):-
    leftdepth(Left, N),
    N1 is N+1.
```

Comment: Thank you, I just realised this from Daniel Lyons comment before! But your answer clarified it even further.